# Lateralus drum part

Tags: drums

I love Lateralus by Tool. But one part always confuses me. The sticking for the drum roll (with cymbals) before the 5/8 bit at 4:45.

Just to clarify, NOT the 5/8 part, but the big cresendo roll before it.

It feels like a paradiddle but I can't figure it out.

Help me, internet. You're my only hope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The later instance looks like an ordinary single-stroke roll of six strokes with the first on the crash, or variations thereof.  You can see him playing it at 11:05-11:15 in this live video:

The earlier instance at 4:45 in the studio recording sounds like the same idea.  Without equalizing the recording or finding a clearer video, my rough guess would be six sixteenths opened with a crash, then three eighths opened with a crash or maybe those are just accents, then the same thing with two crashes, etc. You might have better accuracy if you slow the song down in [Audacity](http://www.audacityteam.org/).